# Android App “Stops Working” after Splash Screen

Tags: splash-screen

splash screen works fine.
but app stops what should i do?

the i tried to search but it didnt work out well...
i need some advice for this matter.

SplashScreenActivity.java

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    EasySplashScreen config = new EasySplashScreen(SplashScreenActivity.this)
            .withFullScreen()
            .withTargetActivity(MainActivity.class)
            .withSplashTimeOut(5000)
            .withBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1a1b29"))
            .withHeaderText("Header")
            .withFooterText("Footer")
            .withBeforeLogoText("Before LoGo Text")
            .withAfterLogoText("After LoGo Text")
            .withLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    config.getHeaderTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    config.getFooterTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    config.getBeforeLogoTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    config.getAfterLogoTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        View easySplashScreen = config.create();
        setContentView(easySplashScreen);

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java (only upper part)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    MenuItem menuSetting;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    DBHelper dbHelper;
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: solved it dont need help ~

Comment: Post your solution @MateuszKim ... It might help someone in the future